# Oracle SQL not printing the even ID's with % operator

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone tell me why the below code isnt working for Oracle SQL.

```
select distinct city from station where id%2=0;
```

The code is for printing city names which are not duplicates for even ID's.
Any other way I can suffice the requirement?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  ..  your  expected  result ,  your actula result and the error message you have

Answer (score 5):

if for `%` you mean  the MODULUS operator used to return the remainder of a dividend divided by a divisor.

you should use  MOD()

```
select distinct(city) from station where MOD(id,2)=0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle SQL has a [MOD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm) function to compute remainders.

```
select distinct(city) from station where MOD(id,2)=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL supports

```
mod(id,2)
```

Additionally, PL/SQL static expressions (not cursors) support

```
id mod 2
```

The unquoted `%` symbol is used for cursor attributes such as `%notfound`.